# Are the communications between AWS services (located via ARN) always using SSL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

As asked in the title, is it by default the communication between AWS services uses SSL? For example, a Lambda function writes Objects to S3, or a Lambda function reads data from Kinesis.

Answer (score 2):

You can check AWS's Services and their supported protocols in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html).

The SDK will always opt for HTTPS traffic unless specified otherwise. You can specify so by changing the `endpoint` attribute for the service you are working with. Just check the link above to fetch the right endpoint for the service you are looking for.

You can see how to do so in the official docs for the SDK, like so:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({endpoint: 'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'});
```

Here's a link for S3's Javascript SDK:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#constructor-property

You also have the option to enable/disable SSL by setting the `sslEnabled` attribute to either `true` or `false`. Even though the docs don't state anything for its default value, I truly believe this flag is set to `true` automatically. Setting this flag will only take effect if the protocol has not been previously specified in the `endpoint` attribute.

And this is extracted from the Java SDK:

> Callers can pass in just the endpoint (ex: "ec2.amazonaws.com") or a
>   full URL, including the protocol (ex: "https://ec2.amazonaws.com"). If
>   the protocol is not specified here, the default protocol from this
>   client's ClientConfiguration will be used, which by default is HTTPS.

I have found a [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=189213) in AWS's forums which states that SSL is always enabled for SDK's requests:

> If you specify AWS.config.sslEnabled = true, all endpoints will use
>   SSL by default. There is no "fallback" to HTTP if HTTPS doesn't work
>   or anything like that.
>
> This can be overridden when creating an endpoint, for example by new
>   AWS.S3({sslEnabled: false}) - that is why it is only a default
>   setting. If you do not explicitly say sslEnabled: false in your code,
>   you can be assured that SSL is used everywhere. And finally, even when
>   specifying sslEnabled: true, if creating a new endpoint explicitly
>   with a full URL, such as http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, will
>   override the sslEnabled setting. To say it in another way, sslEnabled
>   only affects if http:// or https:// is automatically added to hosts
>   specified without specifying a protocol.
>
> And the default is to use SSL for all Amazon services by default, so
>   adding a bucket policy that will limit connections to using SSL only
>   will only block explicit attempts to access S3 without HTTPS (or users
>   of different SDK:s or other access methods).
>
> Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. In your example, the resource is located with a URL. I really would like to know about is when the resource is located with ARNs (thus no https or any protocol is specified).

Comment: Under the hood everything is invoked through AWS's APIs. The ARN is just an identifier to find a resource, nothing else.